# How to Get rid of SalesMagnet from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Window 7 ultimate x64. Recently, the SalesMagnet drives me insane with lots of advertisments! What is it? Anyone could help me remove it?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7:

1. Tap the Windows key and select Control Panel.
2. Then select Uninstall a program.
3. Select SalesMagnet and click Uninstall.

For Chrome:

1. Open your browser and tap Alt+F.
2. Select Settings.
3. Then select Extensions.
4. Click the trash can icon to remove the SalesMagnet extension

From here: http://www.pcthreat.com/parasitebyid-46031en.html

Answer (score -1):

1.Install YAC to remove any threat with a single click. 
2.Once installed, open the program and click on the button 'Examine now' in the Home interface. YAC will then start to scan all malicious programs or junk files hidden in your computer. 
3.After the exam, you can click 'Fix' to finish the cleanup. The whole process will only take a few seconds.

Tips:To guarantee that your computer is in a completely safe condition, we suggest using YAC Anti-Malware function to give your PC a whole detection, here's the steps: 
1.Go to the ""Anti-Malware"" function. 
2.Click the ""Threat Scan"" to start the malware detection. 
3.Click ""finish"" to remove all the detected malware.

See the original article here:[How to Get rid of SalesMagnet adware?(Removal Instructions)](http://www.fixbrowser.org/en/Network-Fix/Browser-Adware/20150422-how-to-remove-SalesMagnet-by-virus-removal-tool-yac.html)